# Simple Search and Grid field not returning results

Tags: ee2, search, simple-search, no-results

EE v2.8.1 - Build Date: 20140314

I have a Grid field that is set to searchable, the columns are also set to searchable. It is in the about channel and is populated using the pages module. I have a simple search form and I continue to get '0' results. I even went so far as to specify the exact channel of the entry I was testing, copy and paste the text from the entry form itself, and still I return nothing.

I went into the field to re-save the field type thinking something was "off". I then went into the entry and re-saved the entry to make sure nothing was "out-of-sync".

My simple form is here:

```
            {exp:search:simple_form 
                channel="about" 
                where="any" 
                form_id="searchForm" 
                result_page="search/results" 
                no_result_page="search/no-results" 
                results="20" 
                show_future_entries="no" 
                status="open"
            }
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control search" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" placeholder="Search...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon icon-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            {/exp:search:simple_form}
```

I am currently using this to see what is returned, if anything.

```
            <h2>Your search for <em>{exp:search:keywords}</em> had <em>{exp:search:total_results}</em> results.</h2>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I've never fought something so simple for so long.

*** EDIT ***

I have done some further testing with a new channel, new fieldset, and new entries. It appears that the rich text field inside of the grid is NOT being included in the search. I have ALL searchable fields selected and am not able to return any results from these entries.

Answer (score 3):

WOW!!! I feel a little embarrassed on this one. I will still post the answer since I have seen several other posts in various sites, be it EllisLab support, here, or others. Another fine example of forgetting something very simple and why reviewing the docs on a regular basis is a great idea.   ;)

Adding the following allowed the search of the entry inside the context of that entry:

```
  search_in="entries"
```

Per the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/simple.html#search-in):

> **search_in=**
>
> search_in="entries", search_in="everywhere", search_in="titles"
>
> This parameter specifies which fields you would like to include in the
>   searching. There are three possible values:
>
> ***entries***: The search will be conducted in the entry fields and titles
>   of your channel. The associated comments will not be included.
>
> ***everywhere***: The search will be conducted in the title, entry fields,
>   and in associated comments.
>
> ***titles***: The search will be conducted in
>   the title of your entries. The channel entry fields and any associated
>   comments will not be included. If this parameter is not set, the
>   search will default to only search by “titles”.

*** CONCLUSION ***
Changing my search tag to the following worked:

```
            {exp:search:simple_form 
                channel="not bogus" 
                search_in="entries" 
                where="any" 
                form_id="searchForm" 
                result_page="search/results" 
                no_result_page="search/no-results" 
                results="20" 
                show_future_entries="no" 
                status="open"
            }
```

*** ADDED BONUS ***
If you would like to search in all channels of the site and don't want to worry about forgetting to go back and add one to your search parameters later, if a channel is added, add the following to your search parameters:

```
channel="not bogus"
```

By using the ***not*** in conjunction with a channel name not used, you will search in all channels not named that. Then you simply have to set your searchable flags accordingly in your field sets.